# What would be the Better db design for the old db structure?

Tags: mysql

i've a old database where i store the data of the holidays and dates in which they are celebrated..

```
id  country     hdate           description     link 
1   Afghanistan     2008-01-19  Ashura          ashura
2       Albania     2008-01-01  New Year Day    new-year
```

the flaws in the above structure is that, i repeat the data other than date for every festival and every year and every country..

For example, I store a new date for 2009 for ashura and afghanistan ..

I tried to limit the redundancy and split the tables as

```
countries (id,name)

holidays (id, holiday, celebrated_by, link) 
// celebrated_by will store the id's of countries separated by ','

holiday_dates (holiday_id, date, year) 
// date will the full date and year will be as 2008 or 2009
```

Now i have some problems with the structure too..

**consider that i store the holiday like Independence day , its common for more countries but will have different dates. so how to handle this and and the link will have to be different too.**.

And i need to list the countries which celebrates the same holiday and also when i describe about a single holiday i need to list all the other holidays that country would be celebrating..

And the most of all , i already have huge amount of data in the old tables and i need to split it to the new one once the new design is finalized...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What about having a n-n relationship?

Table: Country

- Country_ID (PK)

Table: CountryToHoliday

- Country_ID (FK)
- Holiday_ID (FK)

Table: Holiday

- Holiday_ID (PK)

Comment: If i do like that, then i think the redundancy can't be avoided. The main thing i wanted to split up is to reduce the redundancy .. And consider the query where i have to fetch the countries which celebrates veterans day then i've compare three tables again.. 

will it reduce the performance when we refer more tables?

Comment: No, you don't have to compare; you can query the Holiday table for the veteran day record and join the two other tables. Very simple. It will be good to have an index on Holiday as well (i.e. Date)

Comment: Regarding the redundancy; you will end up having no redundant data at all (CountryToHoliday record only exists when a country has a holiday).